# how to change blob url indicator without change its url like youtube

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, video-streaming, blob, bloburls

I was impressed with a youtube video streaming way that uses chunked data and didn't use much traffic resource, so I try to imitate youtube way following this source.

```
    vid.src = blobUrl;
    vid.currentTime = timevalue;
    vid.play;
    xhr.open('POST', '1', true);
    xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send('rs=' + rs + '&rn=' + rn);
    rs = rn;
    rn += ch;
    xhr.onload = function(e){
        if (this.status == 200) {
            var tmp = new Uint8Array(this.response);
            var tmp1 = v8array;
            v8array = new Uint8Array(tmp1.length + tmp.length);
            v8array.set(tmp1);
            v8array.set(tmp, tmp1.length);
            myblob = new Blob([v8array]);
            blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(myblob);
            identify = true;
        }
    }
```

This means add aditional request data to Uint8Array when you play all rs-rn (rangestart-rangeend (ch = chunk range)) and it operate well except some lack occurs when vid.src url is changed, and I founded that youtube's blob-url does not change. NOT using media api, how to change blobUrl indicates natural when you play video without lacks? please help me.

Comment: I hope that when you say "*Not  using media api*" you are not talking about [MSE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Source_Extensions_API), because that's what YT uses.

Comment: I mean that youtube does not use just like mediaSource.addSourceBuffer (not media element). To use Media_Source_Extensions_API that is introduced at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Source_Extensions_API, you should give enough information than youtube and my videos(it only operate only 1% of codec I think :( ). you can check in http://www.leanbackplayer.com/test/h5mt.html

Comment: I didn't gone into prettifying YouTube's sources, but yes I think that's what they do.

Comment: Oh... I gona try to change file header using js. Thank you!